# Android Webview not showing html file after resume

Tags: android, android-webview, android-sdcard

i have a webview that read HTML from SD-card and show it . when user open activity for first time, HTML file load correctly . but in some devices (such as Samsung galaxy series) if close activity and open it again, webview not show anything and is empty.

```
public class page extends Activity {

private static WebView web;
private  int path;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 

    path = bundle.getInt("path");

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPage();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    resetWebView();
} 

// becuase my webview play audio and if close activity sound also playing
private void resetWebView(){
    if (web != null){
        web.loadUrl("about:blank");
        web.destroy();
        web.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}

private void loadPage(){

    String DIR =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myApp";

    if(path != null && web != null){
   switch (path) {
    case 3: {
        //   something like this 
        //  /storage/emulated/0/myApp/1/page_three.html/
        File file = new File(DIR+path+"page_three.html/");
        web.loadUrl("file://"+file);

    }
        break;
    case 2: {
        File file = new File(G.DIR_APP+path+"page_two.html/");
        web.loadUrl("file://"+file);
    }
        break;
    case 1: {
        File file = new File(G.DIR_APP+path+"page_one.html/");
        web.loadUrl("file://"+file);
    }
        break;
    case 0: {
        File file = new File(G.DIR_APP+path+"welcome.html/");
        web.loadUrl("file://"+file);
    }
        break;

    default:
        // do nothing
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This is for API 11 and greater. Adding webview.onResume() inside the onResume() function of fragment solved it for me.

So in your case:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    web.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the activity is destroyed while paused, the Android system may re-create it when the user returns to it later. To ensure that the same data that was originally used to intialise the activity is restored, you need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. I recommend this pattern - this will ensure the correct data is loaded for initial creation, resume after pause, recreation and resume after being destroyed, and when sent a new intent to load new data.

```
static final String ARG_PATH = "path";
protected Bundle bundle = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
// perform other create-time initialisation here
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    bundle = intent.getExtras();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = savedInstanceState;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(ARG_PATH, path);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(bundle != null) {
        path = bundle.getInt(ARG_PATH);
        bundle = null;
        loadPage();
    } else
        web.onResume();
    // if bundle was already null, we were just resumed after pause, not destroyed so no reload is required.
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    web.onPause();    // pause any video etc.
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you leave activity, **finish** the activity, so next time you come, a method **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** must be called again.

Answer (score 0):

i add the following code to webview and problem solved

```
      webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```